# efeito deslizante não funciona com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tenho a seguinte **estrutura**:

```
    <body> 

        <div id="topo">

            <section class="topo">

                <div>

                    <ul id="menuTopo">

                        <li><a href='#alvo'>Link</a></li>

    ...
```

Coloquei até a `div` em uma var

```
    var topo = $('body div#topo section.topo div');
```

Então, depois fiz o seguinte:

```
    $(topo).find('ul#menuTopo li a[href^="#"]').click(function () {
      alert();
      e.preventDefault();
      var id = $(topo).find('ul#menuTopo li a').attr('href'),
        targetOffset = $(id).offset().top;

      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: targetOffset - 100
      }, 500);
    });
```

e o retorno que tive foi que o efeito não ocorre! Nem o `alert` funciona

Mas a **ul** está lá.

Se eu fizer:

```
    $(topo).find('ul#menuTopo li a').click(function () {
    alert();
```

O `alert` funciona!

Onde estou errando?

Preciso fazer um efeito deslizante nos `links#` do menu

Comment: Como seria esse "efeito deslisante"?

Comment: E porque não usar apenas o seletor `a[href^="#"]`?

Comment: Sumback, é um efeito que ao invés de ao clickar o loink desce como um flash até o alvo #, ele descesse suave...

Comment: iamdim: pelo fato de que eu só quero esse efeito ema ul apenas de links e não no site todo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alterei alguns pontos no seu código, espero que ajude.

```
    var topo = $('body div#topo section.topo div');

   //Adição do parametro 'e'

    $(topo).find('ul#menuTopo li a[href^="#"]').click(function (e) {
        //alert();
        e.preventDefault();
        //Refenciar 'topo' como classe css '.topo'
        var id = $(".topo").find('ul#menuTopo li a');
        targetOffset = $(id).offset().top;

        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: (targetOffset - 100)
        }, 500);
    });
```

Comment: Não funcionou! Mas, esse $(this) não pegaria apenas o $(topo)?

Comment: o que está pegando é que se eu coloco apenas o elemento a, o alert funciona. mas se u colcoar todo a[href^="#"]', então o alert não funciona